# quotient of 2-torus by antiholomorphic involution is annulus?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry, moduli-space

I would like to study what the quotient
$$T^2 / \Omega $$
of a closed compact Riemann surface with $g=1$ handles, once a complex structure is chosen, over an antiholomorphic involution $\Omega,$ can be, for various choices of $\Omega.$

In particular, which involution does give the annulus
$$ A=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} | \ a < |z| < c \},$$
with $0<a<c$ real numbers ?

Comment: The inversion you wrote is not defined on the torus. On the other hand, the quotient of the torus by anti holomorphic involution could be an annulus, Llein bottle or Moebius band.

Comment: OK, can you please provide examples of the three?

Comment: Yes, after you correct your question by removing the inversion part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the three examples of quotients of the flat torus. In each case, the torus $T$ will be obtained by identifying ends of the product cylinder $A=S^1\times [-1,1]$ via an isometry $f=(h,id): S^1\times (-1)\to S^1 \times (1)$. In the first two examples, $h$ will be the identity map, in the third example, $h(z)=-z$, where I identify $S^1$ with the unit circle in the complex plane.

1. The (isometric) involution $\tau:  T\to T$ is the projection of the reflection $\sigma_1: A\to A$, $\sigma_1(z,t)=(z, -t)$. Note that the reflection $\tau$ has two fixed circles, projections of the circles $S^1\times (1)$ and $S^1\times 0$. The quotient annulus $T/\tau$ is identified with the sub-annulus $S^1\times [0,1]$.
2. The involution $\tau:  T\to T$ is the projection of the orientation-reversing involution $\sigma_2: A\to A$, $\sigma_2(z,t)= (-z, -t)$. Then $\tau$ has no fixed points and, hence, $T/\tau$ is the Klein bottle (since torus can cover only one nonorientable surface, the Klein bottle).
3. This is the most interesting example. In this case, $\tau$ is again the projection of the involution $\sigma_2$ as in (2), but now $\tau$ has a fixed circle, projection of the circle $S^1\times (1)$ to the torus $T$. Hence, $T/\tau$ has exactly one boundary component, hence, it has to be the Moebius band.

By looking at the Euler characteristic, one can see that every quotient of $T$ by an orientation-reversing involution has to have zero Euler characteristic, hence, it is either the annulus, or the Klein bottle or the Moebius band.

Comment: Moebius strip is obtained also quotienting $T$ by $z \mapsto i\overline{z},$ right?

Comment: @jj_p: it depends on which coordinates on the torus you are using. Just be aware of the fact that the torus in this case is not "rectangular".